# Invalid assignment left-hand side. (line 1, file "Code") after if statements are added

Tags: google-apps-script

The error "Invalid assignment left-hand side." only started to occur after the if statements are added.It used to be ok til i added the variables and if statements.

Tried using single '|' for or.

```
function auto() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var QA = ss.getSheetByName("Quality Alert");
  var QAdata = QA.getRange(3,1,QA.getLastRow() - 2,29).getValues(); 
  QAdata.forEach(function(row, i){

               var customer = row[1] ;
               var part     = row[2] ;
               var s        = row[3] ;
               var id       = row[4] ;
               var fid      = row[5] ;
               var defect   = row[6] ;
               var desc     = row[7] ;
               var reject1  = row[8] ;
               var reject2  = row[9] ;
               var ok       = row[10] ; 
               var url      = row[11] ;
               var depart   = row[12] ;  

    if( 0 < depart <= 7){
      Part1.sendEmail()
    }

    if( depart = 8 ){  
      Part2.sendEmail()
    }

    if( depart = 9){
      Part3.sendEmail()
    }

    if( depart = 10 || depart = 11){
      Part4.sendEmail()
    }

    if( 10 < depart <= 15){
      Part5.sendEmail()
    }

  });// End Bracket for QA Data 
}
```

Expected result is when var depart (a number from 1 to 15) is entered, it will run a particular code from the library(PartN.sendEmail).

Comment: in your if condition instead of using single "=" use "==".

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using "==" instead of "=".